# How do i get css3pie to work on all Joomla 2.5 pages not just default page

Tags: joomla2.5, css3pie

How can I get css3pie to work on all Joomla  2.5 pages?

I have got css3pie working on the first page of my joomla 2.5 site but it is not working on any of the other pages.

It works on `http://localhost/human_affairs2/`.
but doesn't work on `http://localhost/human_affairs2/index.php/our-program`.

From what I can tell is using the same index.php file and the same css file.

This is an example of the css.

```
.whiteBox h3,
.nivo-caption {
    -webkit-border-radius:0px 8px 8px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius:0px 8px 8px 0px; /* Firefox 3.6 and earlier */
    border-radius:0px 8px 8px 0px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: #999 1px 2px 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow: #999 1px 2px 3px;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px #999;

    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}
```

Comment: Where are you inserting that CSS?

Comment: All the css is in a css file. Is that what you mean?

Comment: How are you calling the CSS file? From the index.php in the template or from a module? Is the link hard coded or are you using Joomla variables to calculate the link to the file?

Comment: I am calling it from the index.php in the templates folder with `$doc->addStyleSheet($tpath.'/css/template.css.php?v=1.0.0'); ` This is in the template php `require('reset.css');
require('bootstrap.css');
require('template.css');
require('../../../system/css/system.css');
require('../../system/css/system.css');
require('../../system/css/general.css');
?>` Do you have any ideas why its now working??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got it working using the full url to link to PIE.htc.
`behavior: url(http://localhost/human_affairs2/PIE.htc);`

Found the answer here: 
http://css3pie.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=980

Answer (score 1):

You need to clarify your question: ie. provide your code.  I suggest you check out the documentation on their site [enter link description here](http://css3pie.com/documentation/), as the answer to your question depends on which version you're using (PHP, JS, CSS).  Since it's Joomla, I'd think you should be using the PHP version, and if you are, then you'll need to make sure you're not only calling the function to use PIE on index.php, but on the component views as well.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

instead, you can just put the PIE.htc on the root of the website and just call it from css like

```
behavior: url(PIE.htc);
```

You need to put it in the same folder where .htaccess and other important folders sit (e.g. Administrator etc).

That's how i fixed it.